# How to add child elements attached to parents, through an association table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, the first is an association between parent and child table. Another table contains the contacts attached to parents, I want to add contacts parents to each of their children.
I do not see how to build the sql query

First Table association
"Levels"

Level_id_parent   Level_id_child

```
1               4
1               5
2               6
3               7
3               8
3               9
```

Second Table "Contact"

```
Level_id   Contact_id   Visible
1            45           1
1            56           0
1            73           0
2            12           1
2            13           1
3            122          0
```

In the table "Contact", I want to add the contacts corresponding to LEVEL_1 LEVEL_2.
For the following result:

```
Level_id   Contact_id   Visible
1            45           1
1            56           0
1            73           0
2            12           1
2            13           1
3            122          0
----------------------------
4            45           1
4            56           0
4            73           0

5            45           1
5            56           0
5            73           0

6            12           1
6            13           1


7            122          0

8            122          0

9            122          0
```

should I use a cursor to do this? I'm lost.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You haven't made it exactly clear how all these tables you mention relate to each other.  If you post a schema diagram, it would make your question clearer.

Comment: Just join to `Levels` and `Select` `[Level_2] As [Level_id], [Contact_id], [Visible]`. You can then insert these results back into `Contact` or if you just want the results select this and `Union` it back to a straight select from `Contact`.

Comment: what is your logic/rule for generating the last table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No cursor needed, just a simple UNIONed query:

```
select level_id, contact_id, visible
from contact
union all
select level_id_child, contact_id, visible
from levels l
inner join contact c
on l.level_id_parent = c.level_id
order by level_id
```